# Visual Basic ATM program

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to write an ATM program in Visual Basic with a preview box but whenever I clock the preview button before the proceed button my values "double up". For example if I input 10 into the transaction value box with deposit and hit preview I get 160, but when I then hit proceed a I get 170.

Any idea's where I could be going wrong? I know I have to reset the balance after the preview value but I don't know how.

```
Public Class transactionsGBox
    Const SERVICE_CHARGE_DECIMAL As Decimal = 6.5
    Const PIN As Integer = 9343
    Dim Balance As Decimal = 150

    Private Sub Label2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label2.Click
    End Sub
    Private Sub RadioButton5_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles topUpButton.CheckedChanged
    End Sub
    Private Sub transactionsGBox_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    End Sub
    Private Function withdraw(ByVal amount As Decimal)
        Balance -= amount
        Return Balance
    End Function
    Private Function deposit(ByRef amount As Decimal)
        Balance += amount
        Return Balance
    End Function
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles clearButton1.Click
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles confirmButton.Click
        If pinBox.Text = "9343" Then
            transactionGroupBox.Enabled = True
            previewButton.Enabled = True
            proceedButton.Enabled = True
            pinBox.Enabled = False
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect pin, try again", "Pin Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub Label4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label4.Click
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles clearButton2.Click
    End Sub
    Private Sub exitButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles exitButton.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
    Private Sub previewButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles previewButton.Click
        If depositButton.Checked = True Then
            previewBalance.Text = deposit(transactionValueBox.Text)
        Else
            previewBalance.Text = withdraw(transactionValueBox.Text)
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub proceedButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles proceedButton.Click
        If depositButton.Checked = True Then
            finalBalance.Text = deposit(transactionValueBox.Text)
        Else
            finalBalance.Text = withdraw(transactionValueBox.Text)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by doing three things:

1.) Create a local variable inside Preview Button Click event as a "balance preview" variable that gets defined with the balance variable's value.

2.) Modify the Withdraw and Deposit functions to accept two passed variables (one for the amount and one for the balance).

3.) Modify the preview and proceed click event modules to pass down the appropriate balance variable (either balance for the proceed, or the "balance preview" for the preview).

So the new code for the deposit/withdraw functions would look like:

```
Private Function deposit(amount As Decimal, ByRef result As Decimal)
   result += amount
   Return result
End Function
```

Make sure to include the ByRef on the result variable because you want to pass that one by reference (meaning you want to actually change the value inside the second variable you pass).

New code for previewButton looks like:

```
Private Sub previewButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles previewButton.Click

    Dim balancePreview As Decimal = Balance

    If depositButton.Checked = True Then
        previewBalance.Text = deposit(transactionValueBox.Text, balancePreview)
    Else
        previewBalance.Text = withdraw(transactionValueBox.Text, balancePreview)

    End If


End Sub
```

And the new code for the Proceed button looks like:

```
If depositButton.Checked = True Then

    finalBalance.Text = deposit(transactionValueBox.Text, Balance)

Else
    finalBalance.Text = withdraw(transactionValueBox.Text, Balance)

End If
```

What this will do is pass the BalancePreview variable to the functions if the Preview button is clicked, or it will pass the actual Balance variable if the Proceed button is clicked. Either way, it modifies the actual variable that is being passed. This ensures the Balance variable stays updated only when appropriate.